# Best diet for lots of cycling and 3 kettlebell workouts a week?

Tags: diet, calories, bicycling, kettlebell

I cycle 140 miles a week and do a high, medium and light intensity kettlebell workout.

It seems to me like I need a high carb and high (ish) protein diet to sustain this. Currently I eat anything but find I'm always very hungry. Can anyone recommend a good diet to support this kind of lifestyle? I'm not looking to bulk up or anything like that but I would like my body to be in the best shape possible. Links / books / suggestions - anything would be great as a starting point. Perhaps there's some way I can calculate what I need?

Comment: I would agree with your high carb and high protein diet. And since you just want to be healthy and fit, I would include vegetables and fruits too. And lots of water. If you're really hungry, then, you should eat *(maybe fruits).* Don't deprive your body of what it needs :-p.

Comment: Consider [calculating your TDEE](http://mytdee.com/) and using it to guide your caloric intake.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion that is too much exercises.

140 miles per week bicycling would be somewhere around 7 to 10 hours and burning more around 3500 to 4500 calories in the process.

The kettle bell lifts probably add 1000 calories so that is a lot of calories that you have to balance.

The lifts also increase your anabolism demand and this leads to you not being able replenish the lost nutrients thus constant hunger.

Probably if you are able to replenish your calories you would have digestion working all the time and lead to other problems.

To me it sounds like you have to choose between the amount of cycling and kettlebell lifts. Since you want general fitness probably doing less cycling and keeping the kettlbell lifts is the better option as it works the whole body and you don't end up with muscle imbalances from only cycling.

How much do you have to reduce? I guess until you get rid of the constant hunger stuff.

Comment: This is not a conversation forum, and the OP is not asking for which exercise to drop. They are asking about how to sustain it nutritionally. Your calorie counts are way off (15 mph = 45 calories a mile, 140 miles = ~ 2000 calories for the cycling, and the kettlebell is similarly way off). Additionally, 140 miles a week is a fairly light cycling load. It's a fair bit for a non cyclist, but there are many active cyclists that would do this in 1-2 days.

Comment: @JohnP, op is asking how to sustain that level of exercise because no matter how much he eats he is still hungry. As I wrote, in my opinion that is not sustainable for him, for above reasons. I might be wrong and we are speculating about calories expanded. I do own a PowerMeter, done properly 140miles will burn more then 6000C, don't know how you are calculating. I am not saying there are people that can't sustain it, just that op wasn't seem to be able to di it.

Comment: A powermeter pretty much reflects calories in a direct relationship. Watts/hour X 4 (Since a bicycle is about 25% efficient). So if you sustain 200 watts for an hour, it's ~ 800 calories. Most likely your PM is registering straight calories, not kllocalories (Which is what most food labels are in). And again, it doesn't matter if ***you think*** he can't do that much exercise, you didn't answer the question at all and then guessed at things that might happen if he did eat more.